# using scikit learn regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to learn `scikit-learn` regression using a simple function shown below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor, RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR


def func(x: np.ndarray):
    # x (N, 24), y (N, 2)
    x_mean = np.mean(x, axis=1)
    a = np.sin(x_mean)
    b = np.cos(x_mean)
    y = np.array([a, b]).T
    return y


np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.rand(1000, 24) * np.pi * 10
y = func(x)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

models = [
    GradientBoostingRegressor(),
    RandomForestRegressor(),
    GaussianProcessRegressor(RBF()),
    MLPRegressor(max_iter=1000),
    SVR(),
]

plt.figure(figsize=(5, len(models) * 3))

for i, base_model in enumerate(models):
    name = base_model.__class__.__name__
    model = MultiOutputRegressor(base_model)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)

    x_mean = np.mean(x_test, axis=1)
    plt.subplot(len(models), 1, i + 1)
    title = f"{name}. MSE: {mse:.2e}"
    print(title)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.plot(x_mean, y_test[:, 0], ".", label="y_test[:, 0]")
    plt.plot(x_mean, y_test[:, 1], ".", label="y_test[:, 1]")
    plt.plot(x_mean, y_pred[:, 0], ".", label="y_pred[:, 0]")
    plt.plot(x_mean, y_pred[:, 1], ".", label="y_pred[:, 1]")
    plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("regression_test.png")
```

but the results are not good:

[image]

I think I am not using these regressors correctly.

How should I modify my code?

### update

by reducing the dim of x, I get some good results:

how should I change the code for GP to work with high dim input?

[image]